# Minimum graph cycle basis respect to non-empty pairwise intersection of cycles

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I'm trying to understand the following problem if anyone can help I'll be very grateful

**Instance:** undirected, unweighted, connected graph graph $G=(V,E)$.

**Question:** find a minimum cycle basis $B = \{C_1,\dots,C_\nu\}$ of $G$  (where $\nu = |E|-|V|+1$ is the *cyclomatic number*) respect to non-empty pairwise cycle intersections. More precisely let $B$ minimize:

$$\sum_{C_i, C_j \in B} \cap(C_i, C_j), i \neq j$$

Where $\cap(C_i, C_j)$ is defined as follows

$$\cap(C_i, C_j) :=
 \begin{cases}
   1 & C_i \cap C_j \neq \varnothing \\
   0 & C_i \cap C_j = \varnothing \\
 \end{cases}
$$

And the intersections considered are: edge intersections.

There is a longstanding theory that describes the problem of minimizing cycle lengths (or weights) instead of cycle intersections. The following survey gives a complete picture:

Cycle bases in graphs characterization, algorithms, complexity, and applications
Kavitha T., Liebchen C., Mehlhorn K., Michail D., Rizzi R., Ueckerdt T., Zweig K.A.
(2009)  Computer Science Review,  3  (4) , pp. 199-243.

I couldn't find a similar treatment of the problem of minimizing intersections. Any comment, suggestion or bibliographic reference will be of great  help.